# lintr keyboard shortcut rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, lintr

I am having a problem with the R package *lintr*

I installed it

```
  install.packages("lintr")
```

and everything works fine, the markers pane appears in RStudio and I can 'lint' R files e.g. like this

```
lintr::lint("model_Forecast.R")
```

Now typing this is inconvenient, so would be nice to have a keyboard shortcut and the GitHub package description just describes this:

> This package also includes two addins for linting the current source and package. To bind the addin to a keyboard shortcut navigate to Tools > addins > Browse Addins > Keyboard Shortcuts.

But it does not work for me. Lintr just does not appear for me under addins. So I can't add a shortcut.

What could be the reason? My RStudio version is Version 1.1.463 - a recent version...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this was easy. Just as I posted my question I found the answer myself. There was a difference between the CRAN version und the Github Version. In the CRAN Version the Addins were not yet included.

```
devtools::install_github("jimhester/lintr")
```

Installing the newest version from GitHub solved the problem.